# "[sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through" Need to hide this message!

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, kernel

When you plug an external drive into my Ubuntu server this message pops up "[sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through"...

I would really like it so it stops sending it to the screen. Any ideas on how I can shut it up? :)

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with a

```
dmesg --console-off
```

command.